# Releasing multiple Magazines to Newsstand

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, newsstand-kit

Is this possible? I would like to create a service that would make it easy for people to create Newsstand Magazines.

So in other words, they'd put in the content for the magazine in my service and I'd release it for them in the app store. Would this be possible, or would Apple say no to this? What do you think?

Comment: It might be best to ask Apple.

Comment: Im already in the progress of this, but they are a bit slow. Would love to hear some if some of you other guys had some experiences with this. Some must have, since my post is being down-voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to release an app for each person that signs up. There is no way to automate this process and add apps to Newsstand (you would have to submit each app manually). The only possibility is to create a Newsstand app that downloads magazine info from your site, and then displays the various magazines to the user. However, Apple could reject the app since it mimics core system functionality, and it is a very unprofessional way for the magazines to reach their audience.

Comment: I know I'd had to release an app for each magazine I'd want to publish. I'd like to release it for them though, so they don't have to go through the hassle of releasing an app (an absolute hell for a non-technical person). The question was wether I'd be able to publish magazines on behalf of them? I mean release each app individually on behalf of them?

Comment: Sure, there should not be a problem with that.

Comment: So you don't think there should be any problem in releasing Newsstand Apps on behalf of other people as long as they are in good quality? Have you done this before?

Comment: No, there is nothing against this in the guidelines. As long as the apps are different (i.e. you are not (paraphrased) "simply spamming the App Store with apps"), and they are, then you will be fine.